# PostGIS layer visible in QGIS Browser panel but displayed as not connected in DBManager

Tags: qgis, postgis, dbmanager

[image]

I have added my database as a workshop and you can see the layers in public schema. but whereas in Db manager it is saying NOT CONNECTED. how can I resolve this?
this is running on localhost. on windows with all latest version software

Comment: I don't think it's related to your question (see my answer below), but I'm curious about the python error on your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The message 'Not Connected' is maybe misleading. It just means that DB Manager has been connected yet to the database. Just open the arrow on the 'workshop' item or double click on it and then DB manager will start connecting to your DB and then the message will disappear and you will see the content of your database.

Comment: i have tried that sir, nothing changed or not any popups

Comment: What is the python error? Click on the stacktrace button.

Comment: sorry sir, i uninstalled it, someother group told me, its not properly working in qgis 3.0 and working in qgis2.18. for now, i will try this

Comment: If you don't give us the error in the Python yellow message bar, developers or others won't be able to fix this issue that you got. I have no issues like this in QGIS 3.0